# OpenAPI: Conditional schema of one parameter depending on value of another

Tags: conditional-statements, swagger, openapi

Hi have an OpenAPI specification which contains following:

```
{
  "/mypath" : {
    "get": {
      ...
      "parameters" : [
        {
          "in": "query",
          "name": "input",
          "schema": {
            "type": ###### Problem here #######
          }
        },
        {
          "in": "query",
          "name": "mode",
          "schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "modeA",
              "modeB"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is: I want make the `type` of the `input` parameter being an `integer` if the `mode` parameter is of value `modeA` and `string` if the `mode` parameter is `modeB`.

I tried something with the if-then-else construct, but I cannot see how to reference the two parameters in the `parameters` array.

My second approach was the usage of `oneOf` like

```
  "get": {
    ...  
    "oneOf": [
     {
       "parameters" : [
        {
          "in": "query",
          "name": "input",
          "schema": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        },
        {
          "in": "query",
          "name": "mode",
          "const": "modeA"
        }
      },
      {
       "parameters" : [
        {
          "in": "query",
          "name": "input",
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        {
          "in": "query",
          "name": "mode",
          "const": "modeB"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

But for me it looks not like a valid OpenAPI specification.

So, do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use inheritance with a `discriminator` - the discriminator is a readonly field that tells you the type of your object in the hierarchy, which could be your "mode". https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/

These three schemas model your situation: A `VariantWithStringOrInt` has a readonly `mode` field that is restricted to `A` or `B`, and a field `value` exists that is either `string` or `int`, depending on the value of `mode`.

```
components:
  schemas:
    VariantWithInt:
      required:
        - mode
        - value
      type: object
      properties:
        value:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        mode:
          type: string
          readOnly: true
    VariantWithString:
      required:
        - mode
        - value
      type: object
      properties:
        value:
          type: string
        mode:
          type: string
          readOnly: true
    VariantWithStringOrInt:
      discriminator:
        propertyName: mode
        mapping:
          A: VariantWithString
          B: VariantWithInt
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/VariantWithString'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/VariantWithInt'
      properties:
        someCommonProp:
          type: string
        anotherCommonProp:
          type: string
```

What this will compile to is of course up to your generator and language, so make sure this compiles to something usable for all projects involved.

For example, with openapi-generator-6.6.0 for java this compiles to an interface `VariantWithStringOrInt` which exposes a `getMode` method and two classes which implement the interface: `VariantWithInt` and `VariantWithString`. Those have all the fields as properties, including the common ones. Seems ok if you can get over the explicit casts that you will need.

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. I will have a look at it! :)